# Is it bad or totally wrong to get a horizontally centered page by tuning CSS properties of html tag?

Tags: css

Is it bad or totally wrong to get a horizontally centered page by tuning CSS properties of html tag?

**css code snippet:**

```
<style type="text/css">
    html
    {
        width: 1200px;
        margin: 0px auto;
        background-color: Gray;
    }
    body
    {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

**html code snippet:**

```
<body>any contents go here...</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `html` is the father of every element in the page. If it becomes centered, let's say you want to position something absolutely at the top left/right of your entire page. It will now become relative to the centered `html` element, most likely... and it would be a pain having to offset that effect, which is why I don't recommend doing so.

This is why it's better to center at least the body or a div wrapper.

**EDIT**: It seems like the AP'd element will be relative to the entire viewport in my actual test ( in Fx 3 ), but even so it could be inconsistent cross browser and inconsistent with IE.

You're guaranteed things will go right by centering the wrapper.